# Excel formatting for counting unique variance and sum by cell

Tags: excel, function, spreadsheet, countif

[image]

Above is a screen grab of the excel spreadsheet I am working on. I am mining data from property portals, and in the left hand column is an individual property defined by the name of the agency listing the property - and in the right hand column is the type of property being listed (villa, apartment, castle etc).

I want to write some functions that:

1. count the number of properties listed by each estate agent (I know this is easy manually but scrolling through tens of thousands of properties means this become a laborious process).
2. Count the total number of properties in each property type listed by each agency (So e.g Agency X has 10 apartments, 4 houses, 1 luxury home etc).

Thanks very much everyone using S.O you're awesome !

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please read [ask] and [repro] to enhance your question. Otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: What you need is, exactly, Pivot Tables: Check [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Answer (score 0):

I made a fake dataset as example of what you get with a Pivot Table:

[image]

As you can see, each row represents an agent. Each column represents a property type. Also, last column would be the total of properties for each agent. And last bottom row would be grand totals of each propperty type.